# Can custom text be added to a listview cell?

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, xamarin

In my xaml form i have the following:

```
<ListView x:Name="listView" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=AllResults}"  ItemSelected="OnEmployeeListItemSelected" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" HasUnevenRows="true">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>
                            <ViewCell.View>
                                <StackLayout VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand">
                                    <Label Text="{Binding Result}" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Font="{StaticResource fontL}" TextColor="{Binding TestResult, Converter={StaticResource resultMapper}}" />
                                    <Label Text="{Binding Path=StartedOn, StringFormat='dd-MM-yyy @ HH:mm:ss.fff'}" Font="Medium" />
                                    <Label Text="Test went on for {Binding NoOfHours}" Font="Medium"/>
                                </StackLayout>
                            </ViewCell.View>
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

AllResults, which is the binding for the listview is a List type that contains a ORM based objects from the DB.

```
public class Result
    {
        [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
        public int TestID { get; set; }
        public DateTime StartedOn { get; set; }
        public DateTime EndedOn { get; set; }
        public TimeSpan NoOfHours{ get; set; }
        public string TestResult{ get; set; }

        public Result ()
        {
            StartedOn = DateTime.Now;
            NoOfHours = TimeSpan.Zero;
            TestResult = "";
        }
    }
```

I need help for two things:

1. For the date I tried to use the method mentioned  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6984919/wpf-c-applying-date-format-to-listview), but it just displays as "dd-MM-yyy @ HH:mm:ss.fff"
2. To show "Test went for of x", where x is a Time of hours

Answer (score 0):

1. The property `NoOfHours` is of the `TimeSpan` type which uses [different](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372287%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) format specifiers.
2. To append a string to the binding, use the following syntax: `<Label Text="{Binding NoOfHours, StringFormat=Test went on for: {0:hh}}"/>`

Comment: Hi @Yegor, For number 1, it is a DateTime. I tried using StringFormat=Started on: {0:MM/dd/yy H:mm:ss}. But Still didn't Work. Also I keep getting the "Input string was not in a correct format" error in both scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by using convertor as mentioned [here](http://www.wpftutorial.net/ValueConverters.html). This was more flexible and easier to implement