# WPF ListView Binding with lookup table

Tags: wpf, data-binding

I have events I'm trying to display in a `listview` the events come to me like this

```
public class EventRecord
{
    public uint EventCode{get;}
    public DateTime DateTime{get;}
    //....
}
```

I created an `ObservableCollection<EventRecord>` and bound my `listView.ItemSource` to it.  The problem is I want to display strings that are contained in a seperate collection.  Something like this

```
private Dictionary<uint,EventMessages> messages;
private ObservableCollection<EventRecord> log;

messages[log.EventCode].Description <--- How to bind to this
```

I also need to display the `DateTime` and some other stuff
Thanks

Comment: For messages[x].Description, does the type in `messages` have an EventCode field matching the EventCode in EventRecord, or can you add one? If that's the case, you could do it in a GridViewColumn's CellTemplate with a readonly combobox ([you can hide the arrow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373330/wpf-combobox-without-dropdown-button)). If not, you could do it [with a multibinding/multivalueconverter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13800383/424129). I'm going to mark the latter as the duplicate, but I'd consider the former approach.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [wpf dictionary binding where key=variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13799705/wpf-dictionary-binding-where-key-variable)

Comment: [Formatting a datetime is not a big deal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6984919/wpf-c-applying-date-format-to-listview).

Comment: @EdPlunkett Yes `messages[x].EventCode` would have the same value as `log.EventCode`  what would likely be lighter weight the combo box or the multibinding/multivalue

Comment: Overhead isn't a concern either way. Either way, `messages` will have to become a public property (with a `get`) of either the parent viewmodel that owns the collection of EventRecord, or of EventRecord itself, so you can bind to it in XAML. If it's on the parent viewmodel, the binding will have to be something like `{Binding DataContext.Messages, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListView}}`. With the ComboBox, you'll need `<ComboBox DisplayMemberPath="Description" SelectedValuePath="EventCode" `, plus the ItemsSource binding to Messages as shown above.

Comment: The MultiValueConverter might be simpler, because you don't need a template for that. But they're both verbose. Either solution may involve some new stuff, so let me know if you run into trouble. Just pick the one that looks less horrible to you. They're both mildly horrible, but at least you'll feel like you did what you could.